What kind of a shop or place is the "BINGLE & BLATCH" in Hogsmeade?
In Hogsmeade, there's a place called "BINGLE & BLATCH":

But there isn't really anything inside of it. I don't see any people inside either.
What is this place used for? What is it?

After typing my question, I realized that it has three different entrances and each entrance has a different interior. Quite cool.
Here's an extract from the Harry Potter Wiki:

The shop had an uncanny magical ability whereby it had three doors, and the interior appearance would change depending on which door a customer entered through. One interior showed a clothing shop, while another showed a book shop, and another showed a cauldron shop.

Red Entrance


Green Entrance


Brown Entrance



I noticed this doesn't seem to work on the Switch version. No matter what door I go through, it shows the room as if I went through the green door, and when I exit I come out of the green door every time
